# Can I publish without affiliation?

Tags: publications

Can I publish without affiliation ? Now I am not associated with any university and i want to publish one publication . Is there solution of this problem ?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft that seems exactly right. I should do my homework next time before answering.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can publish without an *official* affiliation. One of the advantages of the anonymous peer-reviewing is that reviewers should be concerned only about the content; Not the author information. Even if it's not an anonymous submission, your name and affiliation should have nothing to do with the quality of your submission.

I have seen affiliations like this:

```
Author Name
Independent Researcher 
author email.
```

Some even with only the name and email address.

Comment: Other things I've seen used as affiliation/address (note that some journals use these interchangeably) - employer; street address (for their home, probably); PO box; "J.B. Smith Institute" where JBS is the author...